# syntax error near unexpected token `elif'

Tags: linux, shell-script

For the code below when i execute  im receiving the

```
checkscript_2.sh: line 43: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
```

```
checkscript_2.sh: line 43: `elif [[ $fdr_count = "0" ]]'
```

```
if [[ $output_count_fdr = "0" ]]

echo "<td align="centre" valign="middle"><font color="red">FDR CUSTOM</td>">>checkscript_customtable.html

echo "<td align="centre" valign="middle"><font color="red">fdr_cust$todays_date</td>">>checkscript_customtable.html

echo "<td align="centre" valign="middle"><font color="red">The table for today has not been created</td>">>checkscript_customtable.html

elif [[ $fdr_count = "0" ]]

then

echo "<td align="centre" valign="middle"><font color="red">FDR CUSTOM</td>">>checkscript_customtable.html

echo "<td align="centre" valign="middle"><font color="red">fdr_cust$todays_date</td>">>checkscript_customtable.html

echo "<td align="centre" valign="middle"><font color="red">$fdr_count</td>">>checkscript_customtable.html


else
echo "<td align="centre" valign="middle"><font color="green">FDR CUSTOM</td>">>checkscript_customtable.html

echo "<td align="centre" valign="middle"><font color="green">fdr_cust$todays_date</td>">>checkscript_customtable.html

echo "<td align="centre" valign="middle"><font color="green">$fdr_count</td>">>checkscript_customtable.html

fi
```

Im not sure what is the mistake im doing here

Comment: add a `then` after the first `if [[ ... ]]`

Comment: You also have issues with your `echo` statements, outputting double-quoted strings that contain double quotes.  Change the outer quotes to single quotes. Consider using a tool such as https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check the syntax of your shell scripts.

Comment: Thank you so much @mosvy . The answer was helpful

Comment: @Kusalananda : im trying to get the output to a html page . That's the reason i have used double quotes

Comment: Since you're having issues with the `echo` commands that isn't addressed by the comments, I will reopen the question. Thanks for bringing this to my attention. I will also answer, unless someone else is quicker than me.

Answer (score 2):

The primary issue is the lack of `then` after the first test.  This is what gives rise to you error message.

Once you have fixed that, you will notice that your `echo` statements do not work as expected.  Let's take one example:

```
echo "<td align="centre" valign="middle"><font color="green">fdr_cust$todays_date</td>">>checkscript_customtable.html
```

This will *not* output the double quotes around e.g. `centre`.  It does not do that because the `"` character right before `centre` is ending the quote that started just before `<td`.

To output this data in the way that you want, I would suggest using a "here-document":

```
cat <<END_HTML >>checkscript_customtable.html
<td align="centre" valign="middle"><font color="green">FDR CUSTOM</td>
<td align="centre" valign="middle"><font color="green">fdr_cust$todays_date</td>
<td align="centre" valign="middle"><font color="green">$fdr_count</td>
END_HTML
```

The the text beneath `<<END_HTML` and before `END_HTML` (the latter *must* not be indented, and must be the only text on that line) will be passed to `cat` which will append it to the `checkscript_customtable.html` file.

The shell will also expand the variables to their values inside the text.

---

As an aside, to reduce the number of output redirections you do in your `if`-`elif`-`else` code further, you can actually get away with doing only one (since all output goes to the same file):

```bash
if [[ $output_count_fdr -eq 0 ]]; then
   # code here
elif ...; then
   # code here
else
   # code here
fi >checkscript_customtable.html
```

This is a way to redirect all output from anywhere in the `if` compound statement to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the problems already discussed, duplicating code is always a bad idea, consider populating variables and then having a single block where you do the prints instead, e.g.:

```
if [[ $output_count_fdr = "0" ]]; then
    color='red'
    msg='The table for today has not been created'
elif [[ $fdr_count = "0" ]]; then
    color='red'
    msg="$fdr_count"
else
    color='green'
    msg="$fdr_count"
fi

fmt='<td align="centre" valign="middle"><font color="%s">%s</td>\n'
{
    printf "$fmt" "$color" 'FDR CUSTOM'
    printf "$fmt" "$color" "fdr_cust${todays_date}"
    printf "$fmt" "$color" "$msg"
} > checkscript_customtable.html
```

Chances are you should be doing whatever you're doing using awk instead of shell anyway though. Post a new question if you'd like help with that.